# From second activity when press home back button do not came back same fragment in a activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, back-button

**In my project 2 activity given -  MainActivity & Second Activity.
in my main activity, I have four fragments, In the 3rd fragment, A button uses to go to the second activity.**

I will implement the below code to go back

**This code came back to me on MainActivity at home Fragment. but I went through the third fragment.so I want to come back to my third fragment.** Please coders help me to solve this.

***Also, help me when I go from fragment to fragment and want to come back to the same fragment.***

In Manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
```

ThirdFragment

```
binding.goToSecondActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent a = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
                a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(a);
            }
        });
```

In Second activity

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActivitySecondBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivitySecondBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Second Page");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

       // code here
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define a class, with a method getInstance accessible globally, that contains the last fragment visited, when you press back you should use the fragment manager to recreate the last fragment (found in the new class) and then, looking at the model of the selected fragment, repopulate it with the old data (if there are inputs/non static datas in the fragment)